# Images in List in Panorama throwing Out of memory Exception

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a Panorama page where list of feeds are coming from previous page which have some images. So if the size of that list increases it throws out of memory exception. Also my Pivot is in template, so I am not even able to do dispose action for images. Please help. Stuck in the issue for a long.

Constants.messageDiscArray, I am setting in previous page to a Constants file. And aslo the Panorama is in a template so I am also not able to perform any function on the images for the garbage collection.
Any help would be appreciated thanks.

**This is my xaml code :**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,0,0">
     <controls:Panorama x:Name="FeedsPanorama" Title="Dashboard Column" ItemsSource="{Binding Constants.messageDiscArray}" >
     <controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Grid Margin="0,-300,0,0">
               <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
               <Image Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="15,319,0,0" Name="image11" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Source="/WpControlsExample;component/Images/assigns.png" />
               <Image Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="340,319,0,0" Name="image13" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Source="{Binding spamURL}" />
               <Image Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="376,319,0,0" Name="image14" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Source="{Binding sentimentURL}" />

               </Grid>
               </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:Panorama>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And below is my C# code

```
public partial class MessageDescription : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<InboxItem> msArray = new ObservableCollection<InboxItem>();

    public MessageDescription()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadPanoramaFeeds();
    }

    private void loadPanoramaFeeds()
    {
        for(int i=0;i< Constants.messageDiscArray.Count;i++){
            msArray.Add(Constants.messageDiscArray[i]);
        }
        this.FeedsPanorama.ItemsSource = msArray;
        this.FeedsPanorama.DefaultItem = this.FeedsPanorama.Items[Constants.messageIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot expect an answer based on this, can you show us some code

Comment: This is my xaml code :

Comment: Edited with Code, Please see if you can get something out of it to resolve the error

Comment: How many pictures do you have? How big are they?

Comment: there are I think 4 or 5 picture for one panorama item, but I just checked even if I remove those pictures its giving same error, I think the panorama is not supporting lot of feeds, cause the case where I am getting error have more that 1K items in it. Is there any limit for panorama, or can we buffer it for 1st 20 and then add later others items.

Comment: Tell me if there any solution to solve this issue, by buffering or this is a bad practice to use panorama for this situation.